# How to change username password of database in hsqldb

Tags: hsqldb

Hi i need to change my username password of my hsqldb. so where and how can I change my username password?. please help me to resolve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Connect with the old user name and execute the statement below

```
SET PASSWORD 'newpassword'
```

If the user which is connected to the database is ADMIN, it can change the passwords of other users with this statement

```
ALTER USER "username" SET PASSWORD 'newpassword'
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an ADMIN user with Username ROOT and Password ROOT:

```
CREATE USER ROOT PASSWORD ROOT ADMIN;
```